# How can I not repeat this code in jquery?

Tags: jquery

I am repeating an IF ELSE statement like so

```
 $('#accountLoginButton').click(function() {




     if($('#topSubscribe').is(":visible")) {

         $('#topSubscribe').slideUp(function(){


            if ($('#topLogin').is(":hidden"))
            {
                 $('#topLogin').slideDown("fast");
            } else {
                 $('#topLogin').slideUp("fast");
            }

         });

     } else {

         if ($('#topLogin').is(":hidden"))
            {
                 $('#topLogin').slideDown("fast");
            } else {
                 $('#topLogin').slideUp("fast");
            }

     }




 });



 $('#subscribeTopButton').click(function() {

     if($('#topLogin').is(":visible")) {

         $('#topLogin').slideUp(function(){


            if ($('#topSubscribe').is(":hidden"))
            {
                 $('#topSubscribe').slideDown("fast");
            } else {
                 $('#topSubscribe').slideUp("fast");
            }

         });

     } else {

         if ($('#topSubscribe').is(":hidden"))
            {
                 $('#topSubscribe').slideDown("fast");
            } else {
                 $('#topSubscribe').slideUp("fast");
            }

     }


 });
```

Basically 2 buttons operating like tabs to show/hide stuff.

As you can see I literally have the same code being repeated in a few different ways a couple times. I have a feeling i could somehow get this down to a few lines of code but my javascript understanding is a bit shady in general.

How do I trim this down the most?

Comment: There is no slideUp prototype that takes a function as first parameter, see: http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/slideUp - saves you asking your next question! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [slideToggle](http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/slideToggle) instead of checking for visibility and then using slideDown or slideUp.

You can replace:

```
if ($('#topLogin').is(":hidden"))
{
     $('#topLogin').slideDown("fast");
} else {
     $('#topLogin').slideUp("fast");
}
```

with:

```
$('#topLogin').slideToggle("fast");
```

This should allow you to get rid of a lot of repetition in your code.

Comment: It won't actually remove the repetition, but it'll reduce the number of code lines =)

Comment: Yes, the logic in the code is flawed anyway. I like your solution.

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like this:

```
function handleVisibilityOf( el, otherEl ) {
  if( el.is(':visible') ) {
    el.slideUp( function() {
      otherEl.slideToggle();
    } );
  }
  else {
    otherEl.slideToggle();
  }
}

$('#accountLoginButton').click( function() {
  handleVisibilityOf( $('#topSubscribe'), $('#topLogin') );
} );

$('#subscribeTopButton').click( function() {
  handleVisibilityOf( $('#topLogin'), $('#topSubscribe') );
} );
```

Comment: Thanks @bobince, too early in the morning here, maybe :)

Answer (score 1):

You can put that code-block into a function and call it in both locations as needed.

Answer (score 1):

Try refactoring it to smaller functions, then you should be able to see duplication more easily.

Answer (score 1):

You're merely running to much code inside your if block. Try this instead:

```
$('#accountLoginButton').click(function() {
    if($('#topSubscribe').is(":visible")) {
        $('#topSubscribe').slideUp();
    }
    $('#topLogin').slideToggle('fast');
}
```

Or you can, as several others have proposed, factor out the repeated code into a separate function:

```
$('#accountLoginButton').click(function() {
    if($('#topSubscribe').is(":visible")) {
        $('#topSubscribe').slideUp(function(){
            $('#topLogin').slideToggle('fast');
        });
    } else {
        $('#topLogin').slideToggle('fast');
    }
});
```

EDIT: Using `.slideToggle()` instead of the if block.

Answer (score 1):

```
function slideBoth(elm1, elm2){
  if(elm1.is(":visible")){
    elm1.slideUp(function(){
      elm2.slideToggle("fast");
    }
  }else{
    elm2.slideToggle("fast");
  }
}


$('#accountLoginButton').click(function() {
  slideBoth($("#topSubscribe"), $("#topLogin"));
}



$('#subscribeTopButton').click(function() {
  slideBoth($("#topLogin"),$("#topSubscribe"));
}
```